# PyQt application issue with matplotlib bar graph x ticks

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5, python-3.7

[image]

[image]

I'm making a application to show graph using python pyqt5 and matplotlib.
here is a issue with graph I don't know why this happen.

You can see the 2 graph image I uploaded.
Second one is what I want to show.
But after show pie graph(There are so many types of graph I used in my application but only after pie graph happen this issue), it work like first image.

So, I wrote code after draw pie graph
`self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()` like this.
But it doesn't change at all.

If I reboot my application it work well.

How I can show my graph like image2 after show pie graph?

this is my code to show bar graph

```
self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.bar(ind, graph1, width, label='price1' )
self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.bar(ind, graph2, width, bottom=graph1, yerr=Std, label='price2')
self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.title.set_text('graph1')
self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.set_xticks(ind)
self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.set_xticklabels(temp['date'], rotation=90 )
self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.legend(loc='best')
self.MplWidget.canvas.draw()
```

this is my code to show pie chart

`self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.title.set_text('pie graph')
 self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.pie(sizes,  labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
 self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.axis('equal')

 self.MplWidget.canvas.draw()
 self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()`

Answer (score 0):

`Axes.pie` sets the aspect ratio of the axes to 'equal' which is what seems to mess up the bar plot. You could try setting `self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.set_aspect('auto')` when plotting the bar plot to reset the aspect ratio to 'auto'. You probably also want to set `self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.set_frame_on(True)`  since `Axes.pie` removes the frame around the plot as well.

Another option could be to use separate widgets for each of the plots and combine them in a `QStackedWidget` or `QTabWidget`.